# How to select elements with a style tag in IE6 with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

We have a CMS that likes to insert inline styles, I have written some code that removes the inline styles adds a class and rewrites the contents of the style attribute into a style tag in the head.

**Example HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p style="width: 50%;">Blah blah blah</p>
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Even more blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Can I get some blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Ooo Ahh blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery function**

```
$.each($('#container [style]'), function(index, el){
    var cssText = el.style.cssText;
    var className = "auto-class-" + index;
    $(el).removeAttr("style");
    $(el).addClass(className);
    $("<style type='text/css'> ." + className + "{" + cssText + "} </style>").appendTo("head");
})
```

**Desired Result HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css"> .auto-class-1 { width: 50%; } </style>
    <style type="text/css"> .auto-class-2 { font-weight: bold; } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p class="auto-class-1">Blah blah blah</p>
        <p class="auto-class-2">Even more blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Can I get some blah blah blah</p>
        <p>Ooo Ahh blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I all the good browsers this works as expected, but in IE6 the jQuery `[style]` selector seems to grab all the elements inside the `#container`. So you get the following instead.

**Result HTML in IE6**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css"> .auto-class-1 { width: 50%; } </style>
    <style type="text/css"> .auto-class-2 { font-weight: bold; } </style>
    <style type="text/css"> .auto-class-3 { } </style>
    <style type="text/css"> .auto-class-4 { } </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p class="auto-class-1">Blah blah blah</p>
        <p class="auto-class-2">Even more blah blah blah</p>
        <p class="auto-class-3">Can I get some blah blah blah</p>
        <p class="auto-class-4">Ooo Ahh blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example above this doesn't cause any issues but on our website where there are over 300 DOM nodes on any given page it's a mess.

The question is how can I select only the DOM nodes with a style attribute in IE6.

Also is there an easy way to write all the rules into one style tag rather than having a separate style tag for each rule.

Comment: Why are you moving inline styles into individual `<style>` elements with jQuery? What do you gain?

Comment: Excuse my unknowledge... IE6 is a browser? And if you bother about ie6 you should be concerned too on users that have JS disabled

Comment: As I see your script is literally translated by IE6 and does exactly what you described. Have you tryed to add a check like:   if( $(className).attr('style') != "" ) {....do than....} or some other sort of pre-verification?

Comment: @thirtydot It's for print style sheets. The inline styles over overrule them, but style tags are fine. @roXon we're using JS to progressively enhance the page, it still works without it. IE6 is still standard browser for staff here. (Booo). I'll give the pre-verification idea a go, thanks.

Comment: If you are satisfied with your code and it's only matter of ie6, you can enclose some relevant changes into:   if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1) == 6){
 ...your ie6 modifications here... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an answer to the specific question you asked, but *it is* what I think you should do.

You said in a comment:

> It's for print style sheets. The
>   inline styles over overrule them, but
>   style tags are fine.

The solution you're using (moving inline styles to `<style>` elements) is not very elegant.

You'd be much better off adding `!important` to every single declaration in your print stylesheet.

```
body {
    color: #444 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
#menu {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Yes, this is ugly, but it's much cleaner than a JavaScript-based solution.

If you'd like some background information:

**See:** http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

> The !important value appended a CSS
>   property value is an automatic win. **It
>   overrides even inline styles from the
>   markup.** The only way an !important
>   value can be overridden is with
>   another !important rule declared later
>   in the CSS and with equal or great
>   specificity value otherwise.

Comment: @roXon: I don't understand your comment. My method will work just fine in IE6.

Comment: @thirtydot Guess what, yep that's right IE6 ignores !important in print stylesheets if the style is already set inline, so while I agree that this seems a better solution it doesn't work for this situation. http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: @Tom Styles: Test this with IE6: http://fiddle.jshell.net/thirtydot/f6m5C/show/light/ - I just did (with IE6), and it's `red` on screen, and `blue` on Print Preview. I can't actually print from my IE6, but Print Preview should be the same. So, my answer *does* seem to work.

Comment: @Tom Styles: Also, that article you linked to is not what we're talking about here. That's saying that `div[style]` won't work in IE6 due to the use of the attribute selector (and it not being supported in IE6). But, you *don't need* `div[style]` to override inline styles; Chris Coyier finally notices this for himself here: http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/#div-comment-56079

Comment: @thirtydot @Tom : well yes, I excuse for my unconstructive comment. Seems after all like a +1 suggestion. And there i give it. In the means of print-style optimisation. Tom, take in consideration this answer and try to fix the ie6 overpopulation of empty styles.

Comment: @thirtydot it seems you are correct. Some carefully placed !important rules and the print stylesheet suddenly start to work. What is the stackoverflow protocol on Marking this as the answer? @roXon got the closest to an answer to the original question with the filtering idea. I got the javascript working by adding an `if(cssText){}` around the last 4 lines of the function.